# Range.End() Confuzzlement

Tags: vba, excel

I have a general question regarding the Range.End() property in VBA.  I've read up on the property 
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221181.aspx), but I'm still confused. Example:

```
    With ws
       lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       MsgBox ("Last row for xlUP is: " & lastRow)
    End With
```

Why is the xlDirection xlUp? Why isn't it xlDown? Is it starting from the bottom row and going up then? I know this is wrong cause I used it on my code (and cause everyone uses xlUp when finding the last used row), but I don't know why. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

End(xlDown) searches from the top down finding the last used cell before a blank cell.  But that might not be the very last used cell if there are blank cells in the data.  Do it your self manually: highlight a column that contains data intermixed with blanks and then press ctrl down - it will go to the cell before the first blank cell.

On the other hand End(xlUp) searches from the bottom of the range upwards for the first used cell that is before a blank cell.  This will always be the last used cell in the range because we started at the bottom.

Comment: @pnuts: good point. Depends whether the cell you start from is blank or not.

Comment: Thanks! I always thought xlDirection started at the first cell in the range, but I see that is not true.