# Can .End(xlUp) skip blank rows/cells at the bottom of an Excel table data range?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I currently have a program that determines the next empty row by using this code:

```
Public Function GetEmptyRow() As Long
    If ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > _
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then
        GetEmptyRow = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Else
        GetEmptyRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
End Function
```

The greater than comparison is there because if the item in the active row is used by more than one person, it creates a new row and nests the second name in column E, with columns A through D being blank.

I was trying to add striped formatting with an Excel table, and now when a new row is added, the blank cells that are in A through D in the data range "stop" the End(xlUp) value, allowing me to change to just one line of code:

```
Public Function GetEmptyRow() As Long
    GetEmptyRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End Function
```

If any rows are deleted at the bottom, however, it returns the row under the last in the range, even if it's blank. Is there a way to skip blanks in an Excel table data range using .End(xlUp)?

**Update**
After reading the suggestions, I ended up changing the code to this:

```
Public Function GetEmptyRow() As Long

    Dim lastRow1 As Integer, lastRow2 As Integer

    lastRow1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.Columns(2) _
    .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lastRow2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.Columns(5) _
    .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    If lastRow2 > lastRow1 Then
        GetEmptyRow = lastRow2 + 1
    Else
        GetEmptyRow = lastRow1 + 1
    End If

End Function
```

Which seems to do the trick. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way but it definitely gets the job done. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You could test if the cell 1 row above the result of  `End(xlUp)`, i.e. a blank row in the table, is empty, and then use `End(xlUp)` again to get to the last populated row in the table. Or you could use the properties and methods of the table to find the last non-empty row, which might be a better approach.

Comment: Note that in your revised code, you should still handle the possibility of there being no empty rows. Your lines `lastRow1 = ActiveSheet...` and `lastRow2 = ActiveSheet...` will throw an error if `Cells.Find` doesn't find anything.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented the change into the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't skip blanks using the `.End` property, it mimics the action that would take place if you clicked a cell and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>end</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> on your keyboard.

- If you start from a non-blank cell, it will automatically stop where the range is blank, **or**
- If you start from a blank cell, it will automatically stop where the range is **not** blank.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end) is the MSDN documentation on the property and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20230559/8305056) is another very good answer on the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would the Find function be able to achieve a similar result?

Comment: The `.Find` function will return the single-cell range of a keyword. I'm not sure how you are hoping to use it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) is the MSDN documentation for `.Find`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I updated the main post with the new code. Thank you!